# how to fix Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent in Angular 10

Tags: angular

using Angular 10 and I found following error in the console here
`templateUrl: './app.component.html',`
`Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.`

my app.component.ts file is

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'task-yt';
}
```

what is this error how could I fix this problem here?

**My app.component.html**

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <app-header></app-header>

    </div>
  </div>
<br>
  <div class="row mt-5 mb-5">
    <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
<hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <app-footer></app-footer>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You have a problem in your template (app.component.html).

Comment: I have edit my question and what is problem with template

Comment: I recommend you Comment (disable) : <app-header></app-header>, then <app-footer></app-footer>, then  <app-footer></app-footer> `one by one` to see which one when is disabled the app work fine. that one has problem